# Angular JS load view2.html from view1.html

Tags: angularjs, html, routes, angular-routing

I have a simple angular JS app in which there is a main container html view page, a left menu for navigation between views.

```
 //Left panel menu links
 <li><a href ng-click="vm.showPanel('View1')">View1</a></li>
 <li><a href ng-click="vm.showPanel('View2')">View2</a></li>
 <li><a href ng-click="vm.showPanel('View3')">View3</a></li>
  //JS function to load view
  vm.showPanel = function (panelName) {

hideAllPanels();

if (panelName == 'View1') {
        vm.isView1Visible = true;
   }
}
```

The above is working fine, now what I want to do is add a button in View1.html called "Next" which will load next view that is view2.html & so on.
Please note both view1.html % view2.html are within a container html page.
Can anyone show me what is the angular way of doing this?

**Regards**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain one variable which contains Views html list, like below, and that can be render it by using `ng-repeat`

**Controller**

```
$scope.viewList = ['View1','View2','View3'];
```

**HTML**

```
 <li><a href ng-repeat="view in viewList" ng-click="vm.showPanel(view )">Next</a></li>
```

More elegant solution would be to re implement you whole show tab and hide tab logic using `ui-router` or `angular-route` as it looks like pure SPA thing.

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9SURXnkVEjnCCxaASWYG?p=preview) for Angular Route

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview) for Angular UI-Router

Comment: Thanks that works nice, is it possible to call the parent page JS function from child page something like $scope.$parent.hideAllPanels().

Comment: @Max surely you can always call parent scope function using `$scope.$parent`

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I am able to get the properties defined in parent scope but when I try to call a parent JS funtions "$scope.$parent.hideAllPanels();", I get a "undefined is not a function" error.

Comment: That means you parent scope doesn't contain `hideAllPanels` method,